# Using .htaccess to redirect only traffic to the root to a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a site set up complete with an index, etc.  I would like to redirect only traffic coming directly to `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/foo.php`.  However, if a user tries to access `www.example.com/index.php` or any of the other existing pages directly, the request should return the appropriate page as normal.  I can't seem to wrap my head around these rewrite rules.  How would I accomplish this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could likely get away with just changing the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) to `/foo.php`:

```
DirectoryIndex foo.php
```

However, if you wanted to use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to actually rewrite the URL, there are a few different ways to accomplish this, but the clearist is to just check if the requested resource is an empty string (the root was requested, and the input to `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` files doesn't contain a leading slash):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /foo.php
```

Any request to the server that is not for `/` will simply be ignored and routed by Apache as normal.

Comment: Worked flawlessly and such a quick response.  Any advice on how to go about learning these rewrite rules well?

Comment: @Oren: Awesome. Outside of reading the documentation, many "typical" cases have been asked and answered here, so it's possible to learn a fair bit from the answers I imagine. If you have a local test server, using [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) with a high `RewriteLogLevel` can help you get a feel for what's going on internally. Most of it's just regular expressions, trickery, and trial and error though, heh, so it takes a bit of getting used to.